# If $S\subseteq(0,\infty)$ is uncountable, must there exist a strictly decreasing sequence $s_n\in S$ with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n=\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If not, then there must be only finitely many points $>\frac{1}{n}$ for each $n$. Since $S$ is uncountable, any strictly decreasing sequence $s_n\in S$ with $s_n\rightarrow 0$ must miss out uncountably many points in $S$.

Is it possible to construct a strictly decreasing sequence from this for which the series diverges?

Comment: Can you show that if there are only finitely many points $>{1\over n}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $S$ is countable?

Comment: The question in the title is not clear to me. What about a constant sequence? You just need $S$ to be nonempty.

Comment: Thanks Noah, I managed it now.

Comment: Kosh - have edited it now. I meant strictly decreasing so of course no constant sequences allowed.